# Dynamodb getBatchItem ValidationException

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

Getting ValidationException when I run batchGetItem function on dynamodb table . I am giving both hash key and range key under keys list. Here are request and response .

Request:

```
var params = {"RequestItems":{"table":{"Keys":[{"hash_key":{"S":"xx.xxx.xxx.xxx"}},{"range_key":{"S":"xxxxx"}}]}}};

dynamodb.batchGetItem(params,function(err, res) {if(err) {console.log(err)}else{console.log(res);}});
```

Response:

```
{ [ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema]
  message: 'The provided key element does not match the schema',
  code: 'ValidationException',
  time: Tue Jun 30 2015 17:34:07 GMT-0400 (EDT),
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 0 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the AWS Node JS has a bug, in that we need not mention the data type for the keys.

I tried this and it worked well

```
{
"RequestItems":{
  "<TableName>":{
    "Keys":[
         {"<HashKeyName>":"<HashKeyValue1>", "<RangeKeyName>":"<RangeKeyValue2>"},
         {"<HashKeyName>":"<HashKeyValue2>", "<RangeKeyName>":"<RangeKeyValue2>"}
        ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get this error when the schema of your table does not match the key schema of the keys you provided. You provided a key with Hash=String and Range=String. What is the schema of your table? You can use the [DescribeTable](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeTable.html) API to get the schema of your table.

Comment: Yes, both Hash and Range are string . It seems like some abnormal behavior on AWS side and I initiated a technical support ticket. No resolution still.